# Opening all links with a certain textContent in new tabs

Tags: javascript

How to open all links with a certain textContent in new tabs?

The text content is 'edit' (without quote marks).

Here's what I tried:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    if (link.textContent == 'edit') {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
}
```

This doesn't return all links, and instead returns undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use link.href, url is undefined in your code something like this:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
var link = links[i];
if (link.textContent == 'edit') {
    window.open(link.href, '_blank');
}
}
```

```html
<a href='stackoverflow.com'>edit</a>
```

Comment: Something interesting. The `edit` link seems lowercase on the fly but on the devtool (DOM) the textContent appeared capitalized as `Edit`. At the start the above code didn't work with it, till I changed it from `edit` to `Edit` as in the DOM and than it worked like a charm (Firefox prevented the popups but I ordered it to allow popups and then the charm happened). Deep thanks Dij!